# TensorFlow - numpy-like tensor indexing

Tags: python, tensorflow

In numpy, we can do this:

```py
x = np.random.random((10,10))
a = np.random.randint(0,10,5)
b = np.random.randint(0,10,5)
x[a,b] # gives 5 entries from x, indexed according to the corresponding entries in a and b
```

When I try something equivalent in TensorFlow:

```
xt = tf.constant(x)
at = tf.constant(a)
bt = tf.constant(b)
xt[at,bt]
```

The last line gives a "Bad slice index tensor" exception. It seems TensorFlow doesn't support indexing like numpy or Theano.

Does anybody know if there is a TensorFlow way of doing this (indexing a tensor by arbitrary values). I've seen the tf.nn.embedding part, but I'm not sure they can be used for this and even if they can, it's a huge workaround for something this straightforward.

(Right now, I'm feeding the data from `x` as an input and doing the indexing in numpy but I hoped to put `x` inside TensorFlow to get higher efficiency)

Comment: this issue seems to address exactly this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206

Answer (score 18):

You can actually do that now with [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd). Let's say you have a matrix `m` like the following:

```
| 1 2 3 4 |
| 5 6 7 8 |
```

And you want to build a matrix `r` of size, let's say, 3x2, built from elements of `m`, like this:

```
| 3 6 |
| 2 7 |
| 5 3 |
| 1 1 |
```

Each element of `r` corresponds to a row and column of `m`, and you can have matrices `rows` and `cols` with these indices (zero-based, since we are programming, not doing math!):

```
       | 0 1 |         | 2 1 |
rows = | 0 1 |  cols = | 1 2 |
       | 1 0 |         | 0 2 |
       | 0 0 |         | 0 0 |
```

Which you can stack into a 3-dimensional tensor like this:

```
| | 0 2 | | 1 1 | |
| | 0 1 | | 1 2 | |
| | 1 0 | | 2 0 | |
| | 0 0 | | 0 0 | |
```

This way, you can get from `m` to `r` through `rows` and `cols` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

m = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
rows = np.array([[0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]])
cols = np.array([[2, 1], [1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 0]])

x = tf.placeholder('float32', (None, None))
idx1 = tf.placeholder('int32', (None, None))
idx2 = tf.placeholder('int32', (None, None))
result = tf.gather_nd(x, tf.stack((idx1, idx2), -1))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    r = sess.run(result, feed_dict={
        x: m,
        idx1: rows,
        idx2: cols,
    })
print(r)
```

Output:

```
[[ 3.  6.]
 [ 2.  7.]
 [ 5.  3.]
 [ 1.  1.]]
```

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Well the exact spec of what `tf.gather_nd` is a bit complicated, you can check it in the docs. But basically, the idea is I want a matrix `result` of, say, MxN, were each element is taken from another matrix `x`. For each element I have the corresponding row and column of `x`; these are `idx1` and `idx2`. I stack these two to get a MxNx2 tensor, let's call it `idx12`. `tf.gather_nd` uses the last dimension of `idx12` (which has size 2, like the number of dimensions in `x`), to create two-dimensional indices that are used to look up the elements that go into `result`.

Comment: Please add those to your answer rand I will upvote - docs are, ugh, somewhat lacking. You should still explain what the relation of MxN is to idx1/2

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I've updated the answer with more context and explanations. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 10):

LDGN's comment is correct.  This is not possible at the moment, and is a requested feature.  If you follow [issue#206 on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206) you'll get updated if/when this is available.  Many people would like this feature.

Answer (score 2):

For `Tensorflow 0.11`, basic indexing has been implemented. More advanced indexing (like boolean indexing) is still missing but apparently is planned for future versions.

Advanced indexing can be tracked with https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4638