# Tensorflow "map operation" for tensor?

Tags: python, functional-programming, tensorflow

I am  adapting the [cifar10 convolution example](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py) to my problem.  I'd like to change the data input from a design that reads images one-at-a-time from a file to a design that operates on an already-in-memory set of images.  The original `inputs()` function looks like this:

```
read_input = cifar10_input.read_cifar10(filename_queue)
reshaped_image = tf.cast(read_input.uint8image, tf.float32)
# Crop the central [height, width] of the image.
resized_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(reshaped_image,
                                                     width, height)
```

In the original version, `read_input` is a tensor containing one image.

I keep all my images in RAM, so instead of using `filename_queue`, I have one huge `images_tensor = tf.constant(images)`, where `images_tensor.shape` is (something, 32, 32, 3).

My question is very-very basic:  what is the best way to apply some function (`tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad` in my case) to all elements of  `images_tensor`?

Iterating is problematic in tensorflow, with limited slices([TensorFlow - numpy-like tensor indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736795/tensorflow-numpy-like-tensor-indexing)).  Is there a solution to achieving this using just one command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few answers - none quite as elegant as a map function.  Which is best depends a bit on your desire for memory efficiency.

(a)  You can use `enqueue_many` to throw them into a [`tf.FIFOQueue`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#FIFOQueue) and then dequeue and `tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad` an image at a time, and concat it all back into one big smoosh.  This is probably slow.  Requires N calls to run for N images.

(b)  You could use a single placeholder feed and run to resize and crop them on their way in from your original datasource.  This is possibly the best option from a memory perspective, because you never have to store the unresized data in memory.

(c)  You could use the [`tf.control_flow_ops.While`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py#L1077) op to iterate through the full batch and build up the result in a `tf.Variable`.  Particularly if you take advantage of the parallel execution permitted by while, this is likely to be the fastest approach.

I'd probably go for option (c) unless you want to minimize memory use, in which case filtering it on the way in (option b) would be a better choice.

Answer (score 10):

As of version 0.8 there is `map_fn`. From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn):

> map_fn(fn, elems, dtype=None, parallel_iterations=10, back_prop=True,
> swap_memory=False, name=None)

> map on the list of tensors unpacked from `elems` on dimension 0.

> This map operator repeatedly applies the callable `fn` to a sequence of elements from first to last. The elements are made of the tensors unpacked from `elems`. `dtype` is the data type of the return value of `fn`. Users must provide `dtype` if it is different from the data type of `elems`.

> Suppose that `elems` is unpacked into `values`, a list of tensors. The shape of the result tensor is `[len(values)] + fn(values[0]).shape`.

> Args:

> fn: The callable to be performed.

> elems: A tensor to be unpacked to apply `fn`.

> dtype: (optional) The output type of `fn`.

> parallel_iterations: (optional) The number of iterations allowed to run
> in parallel.
> back_prop: (optional) True enables back propagation.
> swap_memory: (optional) True enables GPU-CPU memory swapping.
> name: (optional) Name prefix for the returned tensors.

> Returns:

> A tensor that packs the results of applying `fn` to the list of tensors
> unpacked from `elems`, from first to last.

> Raises:

> TypeError: if `fn` is not callable.

> Example:

````
  elems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  squares = map_fn(lambda x: x * x, elems)
  # squares == [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
  ```
````

Comment: I can't find anything online either - the above (and I've completed it) cam from

    import tensorflow as tf
    help(tf.map_fn)

Just be sure you're version is 0.8 or later.

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow provides a couple of [higher-order functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/functional_ops) and one of them is [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn). The usage is very easy: you define your mappping and apply it to the tensor:

```
variable = tf.Variable(...)
mapping = lambda x: f(x)
res = tf.map_fn(mapping, variable)
```