# TensorFlow: using a tensor to index another tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a basic question about how to do indexing in TensorFlow.

In numpy:

```
x = np.asarray([1,2,3,3,2,5,6,7,1,3])
e = np.asarray([0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1])
#numpy 
print x * e[x]
```

I can get

```
[1 0 3 3 0 5 0 7 1 3]
```

How can I do this in TensorFlow?

```
x = np.asarray([1,2,3,3,2,5,6,7,1,3])
e = np.asarray([0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1])
x_t = tf.constant(x)
e_t = tf.constant(e)
with tf.Session():
    ????
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736795/tensorflow-numpy-like-tensor-indexing?rq=1
isn't it what you're asking about?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Fortunately, the exact case you're asking about is supported in TensorFlow by [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather):

```
result = x_t * tf.gather(e_t, x_t)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(result)  # ==> 'array([1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 1, 3])'
```

The `tf.gather()` op is less powerful than [NumPy's advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html): it only supports extracting full slices of a tensor on its 0th dimension. Support for more general indexing has been requested, and is being tracked in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206).

Comment: Tensorflow now has a more powerful `tf.gather_nd()` op.

Comment: Also, `tf.gather` now supports any axis, not only the 0th dimension, with the argument `axis`.