# How to use a tensor for indexing another tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `data` tensor of dimensios `[B X N X 3]`, and I have an `indices` tensor of dimensions `[B X M]`. I wish to extract a `[B X M X 3]` tensor from the `data` tensor using the `indices` tensor.

I have this code that works :

```
new_data= []    
for i in range(B):
        new_data.append(tf.gather(data[i], indices[i]))
new_data= tf.stack(new_data)
```

However, I am sure it is not the right way to do this. Does anyone know a better way? (I guess I should use `tf.gather_nd()` somehow but I couldn't figure out how)

I have seen several answers to similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842598/tensorflow-using-a-tensor-to-index-another-tensor). However I could not find the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tf.gather_nd()` with code like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# B = 3
# N = 4
# M = 2
# [B x N x 3]
data = tf.constant([
    [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]],
    [[100, 101, 102], [103, 104, 105], [106, 107, 108], [109, 110, 111]],
    [[200, 201, 202], [203, 204, 205], [206, 207, 208], [209, 210, 211]],
    ])

# [B x M]
indices = tf.constant([
    [0, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [3, 2],
    ])

indices_shape = tf.shape(indices)

indices_help = tf.tile(tf.reshape(tf.range(indices_shape[0]), [indices_shape[0], 1]) ,[1, indices_shape[1]]);
indices_ext = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(indices_help, 2), tf.expand_dims(indices, 2)], axis = 2)
new_data = tf.gather_nd(data, indices_ext)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('data')
    print(sess.run(data))
    print('\nindices')
    print(sess.run(indices))
    print('\nnew_data')
    print(sess.run(new_data))
```

`new_data` will be:

```
[[[  0   1   2]
  [  6   7   8]]

 [[103 104 105]
  [109 110 111]]

 [[209 210 211]
  [206 207 208]]]
```

Comment: It works ! but can you explain what is the logic behind the three rows of code that do it (`indices_help`, `indices_ext `, `new_data `)?

Comment: `tf.gather_nd` needs indices of slices (two coordinates `<b,n>`), but we have only one coordinate `<n>`, with implicit coordinate `b` in `indices` array. Therefore, we should expand every element of `indices` by adding index of _batch_. This is it. First we make `indices_help` with indices of batch, and then concatenate it with source `indices`