# using placeholder in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 12, 5])
step = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
```

I use placeholder in tensorflow. The input shape is `[None, 12, 5]` and the step shape is `[None]`, and I want to obtain the out shape is `[None, 5]` . The values in step are between `[0, 11]`.

Comment: This question is not about `tf.placeholder`. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530786/how-to-use-a-tensor-for-indexing-another-tensor-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
step = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 5])
```