# index rows from 2D tensor

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have a 2D tensor A of floats, and a 1D tensor B of ints. The numbers in B represent indices to the rows of A. How do I efficiently perform a lookup of this indices inside a tensorflow graph?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried [tf.gather()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) ?

See also this question: [TensorFlow: using a tensor to index another tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842598/tensorflow-using-a-tensor-to-index-another-tensor)

Comment: No I had not. Thanks. Turns out this code worked `tf.diag_part(tf.gather(A,B, axis=1))`