# Keras Value Error in Custom Loss Function

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, tensor

## EDIT:

Following this link: [TensorFlow: using a tensor to index another tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842598/tensorflow-using-a-tensor-to-index-another-tensor)

I've got near my solution.

```
def my_loss(yTrue,yPred):

 pred_casted=K.cast(yPred, "int32")
 real_pred=K.gather(t_best_x, pred_casted)
 true_casted=K.cast(yTrue, "int32")
 real_true=K.gather(t_best_x, true_casted)
 real_loss=K.difference(real_pred, real.true) #i actually don’t know the name of this function, but I’m positive something like this exist
 mean_loss=K.mean(real_loss, axis=-1)

 return mean_loss
```

But when I try to train the model, I get the following error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 371, in make_tensor_proto
>       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")

***Any suggestion about how to solve this and why this is caused is strongly appreciated. Note: using the commented "classical_loss_mse" everything works.***

Full stack of the error in the end of the page.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

### ORIGINAL TEXT

I have your classical Keras NN with a custom Loss function

```
network.compile(loss=my_loss, optimizer='Adam', metrics=['mse'])
```

I am trying to create a custom loss function (my_loss)

```
def my_loss(yTrue,yPred):
```

The value of each prediction is a float between 0 and 1000. 
I have an array containing, for each prediction of my NN, a "fitness" of the result. 
Like this:

```
fitness[int(prediction)] = 0.8 #example
len(my_array)
> 1000
```

The concept of the loss function i want to create (I need this) is:

> 1 - my_array[int(yPred)]

Now, is not like I can do int(yPred)... yPred is a Tensor. How can I make this work?

I will try to explain more properly WHAT exactly I want using a pseudo-notworking-example:

```
def my_loss(yTrue,yPred):
    true_loss=[]    
    for prediction in yPred:
        true_loss.append(1-fitness[round(prediction)]) # fitness[round(any yTrue)] = 1
    return true_loss
```

Note: fitness is a normal list containing normal floats

### FULL STACK ERROR

> File
>   "/home/federico/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "/home/federico/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 101, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/home/federico/CLionProjects/monte/EXP2-STILLNOTWORKING.py",
>   line 201, in 
>       callbacks=[TrainValTensorBoard(log_dir='./logs/'+time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-")
>   + name, histogram_freq=0, write_graph=False, write_images=False),callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
>   patience=200, mode='auto')]) # Data for evaluation
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line
>   960, in fit
>       validation_steps=validation_steps)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 1634, in fit
>       self._make_train_function()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 990, in _make_train_function
>       loss=self.total_loss)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py",
>   line 87, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/optimizers.py",
>   line 432, in get_updates
>       m_t = (self.beta_1 * m) + (1. - self.beta_1) * g
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py",
>   line 885, in binary_op_wrapper
>       y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 836, in convert_to_tensor
>       as_ref=False)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 926, in internal_convert_to_tensor
>       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py",
>   line 229, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
>       return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py",
>   line 208, in constant
>       value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py",
>   line 371, in make_tensor_proto
>       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
>
> ValueError: None values not supported.

Comment: What's the point of having an external array with the finesses?

Comment: @Ubut My neural network has, as inputs, the features of a problem, and another parameter which is the "fitness". As output, there is an X between 1 to 1000. The idea is that training the NN like this brings it to learn a strong difference between what is good and what is bad, and when I want a prediction, i set the "fitness" to 1. Of course, the NN will not give me the best result, but I need to check if it's a good result, checking its actual fitness!

Comment: Did you look at this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842598/tensorflow-using-a-tensor-to-index-another-tensor

Comment: @Ubut I've editet the question