# how does tensorflow indexing work

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having trouble understanding a basic concept with tensorflow. How does indexing work for tensor read/write operations? In order to make this specific, how can the following numpy examples be translated to tensorflow (using tensors for the arrays, indices and values being assigned):

```
x = np.zeros((3, 4))
row_indices = np.array([1, 1, 2])
col_indices = np.array([0, 2, 3])
x[row_indices, col_indices] = 2
x
```

with output:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.]])
```

... and ...

```
x[row_indices, col_indices] = np.array([5, 4, 3])
x
```

with output:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  0.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.]])
```

... and finally ...

```
y = x[row_indices, col_indices]
y
```

with output:

```
array([ 5.,  4.,  3.])
```

Comment: Many things that you can do with numpy are not supported in tensorflow. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736795/tensorflow-numpy-like-tensor-indexing Maybe you can explain more what you are trying to accomplish by updating those matrix values and someone can answer how to achieve that result in tensorflow.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'd like to try several image augmentations (not yet available in the tensorflow library) to hopefully improve the generality of the image classification network that gets learned. I don't need gradiants to flow through these ops and I can do it easily on the CPU but that becomes a huge performance bottleneck. I think I should be able to do what I need to with Yaroslav's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's github issue [#206](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206) to support this nicely, meanwhile you have to resort to verbose work-arounds

The first example can be done with `tf.select` that combines two same-shaped tensors by selecting each element from one or the other

```py
tf.reset_default_graph()
row_indices = tf.constant([1, 1, 2])
col_indices = tf.constant([0, 2, 3])
x = tf.zeros((3, 4))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# get list of ((row1, col1), (row2, col2), ..)
coords = tf.transpose(tf.pack([row_indices, col_indices]))

# get tensor with 1's at positions (row1, col1),...
binary_mask = tf.sparse_to_dense(coords, x.get_shape(), 1)

# convert 1/0 to True/False
binary_mask = tf.cast(binary_mask, tf.bool)

twos = 2*tf.ones(x.get_shape())

# make new x out of old values or 2, depending on mask 
x = tf.select(binary_mask, twos, x)

print x.eval()
```

gives

```py
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  2.]]
```

The second one could be done with `scatter_update`, except `scatter_update` only supports on linear indices and works on variables. So you could create a temporary variable and use reshaping like this. (to avoid variables you could use `dynamic_stitch`, see the end)

```py
# get linear indices
linear_indices = row_indices*x.get_shape()[1]+col_indices

# turn 'x' into 1d variable since "scatter_update" supports linear indexing only
x_flat = tf.Variable(tf.reshape(x, [-1]))

# no automatic promotion, so make updates float32 to match x
updates = tf.constant([5, 4, 3], dtype=tf.float32)

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
sess.run(tf.scatter_update(x_flat, linear_indices,  updates))

# convert back into original shape
x = tf.reshape(x_flat, x.get_shape())

print x.eval()
```

gives

```py
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 5.  0.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  3.]]
```

Finally the third example is already supported with `gather_nd`, you write

```py
print tf.gather_nd(x, coords).eval()
```

To get

```py
[ 5.  4.  3.]
```

**Edit, May 6**

The update `x[cols,rows]=newvals` can be done without using Variables (which occupy memory between session run calls) by using `select` with `sparse_to_dense` that takes vector of sparse values, or relying on `dynamic_stitch`

```py
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.zeros((3, 4))
row_indices = tf.constant([1, 1, 2])
col_indices = tf.constant([0, 2, 3])

# no automatic promotion, so specify float type
replacement_vals = tf.constant([5, 4, 3], dtype=tf.float32)

# convert to linear indexing in row-major form
linear_indices = row_indices*x.get_shape()[1]+col_indices
x_flat = tf.reshape(x, [-1])

# use dynamic stitch, it merges the array by taking value either
# from array1[index1] or array2[index2], if indices conflict,
# the later one is used 
unchanged_indices = tf.range(tf.size(x_flat))
changed_indices = linear_indices
x_flat = tf.dynamic_stitch([unchanged_indices, changed_indices],
                           [x_flat, replacement_vals])
x = tf.reshape(x_flat, x.get_shape())
print x.eval()
```

Comment: These examples are very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: co-worker suggested to use `dynamic_stitch` instead of Variables, updated the recipes

Comment: is this still the best way?

Comment: Probably obsolete for tf2.x