# assign certain entries of Tensor, like set_subtensor of Theano

Tags: tensorflow

Can I just assign values to certain entries in a tensor? I got this problems when I compute the cross correlation matrix of a NxP feature matrix `feats`, where N is observations and P is dimension. Some columns are constant so the standard deviation is zero, and I don't want to devide by `std` for those constant column. Here is what I did:

`fmean, fvar = tf.nn.moments(feats, axes = [0], keep_dims = False)
    fstd = tf.sqrt(fvar)
    feats = feats - fmean
    sel = (fstd != 0)
    feats[:, sel] = feats[:, sel]/ fstd[sel]
    corr = tf.matmul(tf.transpose(feats), feats)`

However, I got this error: `TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment`. Is there any workaround for such issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `feats` a `tf.Variable` and use `tf.scatter_update` to update locations selectively.

It's a bit awkward in that `scatter_update` needs a list of linear indices to update, so you'd need to convert your `[:, sel]` implicit 2D specification into explicit list of 1D indices. There's example of constructing 1D indices from 2D [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37062811/419116)

There's some work in simplifying this kind of use-case in issue [#206](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206)

Comment: I see. Will give it a try. Thanks!