# How to clear entries in a Tensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

After some computations I obtain a Tensor **x** of shape (128, 128, 32). 
How can I achieve the same behaviour as in the next code?

`x[:, :, 1:] = 0`

Practically, I would like to clear all entries except for one matrix.

The tensor is obtained inside a session and i would like to clear the entries in the same session.

What's the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

As of 0.10, TensorFlow doesn't have advanced indexing usable for this purpose so you need to reshape to vector, assign to set of linear indices, then reshape back. You can do this assignment on vector by using variables+scatter_update or dynamic_stitch as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061808/how-does-tensorflow-indexing-work/37062811#37062811)