# Tensorflow scatter_update and backpropagation

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to run a neural network to compute vector embeddings of structured objects like graphs. So I'll have an embedded representation for each graph which I've stored in the variable `U` for all graphs in my training set.

The problem I'm facing is that I need to do some an update/assign of `U` before calculating the gradients. Scatter_update breaks the auto differentiation needed for back propagation. I can't use the `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` because of the manual update required in the algorithm.

Is there anyway to do this? I've attached the code here.

```
# Create Hyperparameters
d = 3 
T = 3 
phases = 500 
max_nodes = gtrain.max_nodes
num_classes = gtrain.num_classes
num_graphs = gtrain.graphs.shape[0]

Ug       = np.empty(T, dtype='object')
int_wx1  = np.empty(T, dtype='object')
int_l    = np.empty(T, dtype='object')
int_wl1  = np.empty(T, dtype='object')
int_relu = np.empty(T, dtype='object')

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Feed dictionary
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[max_nodes])
gidx = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[])
adj = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[max_nodes, max_nodes])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[num_classes])

# Node Representation
U = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_graphs, max_nodes, d]))

w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[d],stddev=0.1))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[d, d],stddev=0.1))

u = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[num_classes, d],stddev=0.1))

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

# Debug Calls
# x = tf.Print(x,[x],"Node labels: ")

for t in range(T):
    Ug[t] = tf.gather(U, gidx)
    int_wx1[t] = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(x, shape=[max_nodes, 1]), tf.reshape(w1, shape=[1, d]))

    int_l[t] = tf.matmul(adj, Ug[t])
    int_wl1[t] = tf.matmul(int_l[t], w2) 
    int_relu[t] = tf.nn.relu(int_wx1[t] + int_wl1[t])

    U_update = tf.scatter_update(U, gidx, int_relu[t])

# Debug Calls
#y_ = tf.Print(y_,[y_],"Labels: ")
#w1 = tf.Print(w1,[w1],"Weights 1: ")
#w2 = tf.Print(w2,[w2],"Weights 2: ")

Uwg = tf.gather(U_update, gidx)

wg = tf.reduce_sum(Uwg, 0)
relug = tf.nn.relu(wg)
#y1 = tf.Print(y1,[y1],"y1: ")
#matmul1 = tf.Print(matmul1,[matmul1],"Matmul1: ")

matmul = tf.matmul(u, tf.reshape(relug, shape=[d,1]))
#matmul = tf.Print(matmul,[matmul],"Matmul: ")

y = tf.reshape(tf.nn.softmax(matmul), shape=[num_classes])
#y = tf.Print(y,[y],"Output: ")

entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(y,1e-10,1.0)))
#entropy = tf.Print(entropy,[entropy],"Entropy: ")

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(entropy)
#cross_entropy = tf.Print(cross_entropy,[cross_entropy],"Cross Entropy: ")

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

for i in range(phases):
    batch = gtrain.next_batch()
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], gidx: batch[1], adj: batch[2], y_: batch[3]})
```

Comment: You can use `dynamic_stitch` instead of `scatter_update` to do things in a funcional way, as shown here -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/37062811/419116

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I've now replaced the `tf.scatter_update` with `U = tf.dynamic_stitch([tf.range(num_graphs), gidx], [U, Ug[t]])` but now `train_step.run` is no longer running any of the previous steps in the chain. It's just computing the cross_entropy with zeros for `U` and not updating any values.

Comment: maybe you need to add some logic to update your variable? IE, you can have `dynamic_stitch` solution for differentiation purposes, but also have `scatter_update` ops that you run separately to update the variables

Comment: Could you perhaps link me to a good example where we have to separate computations flows (one with the update and the other with learning). In my example above the initial for loop is the fixed point iteration to update my embeddings and then we perform a single relu and run a softmax to classify  and this is where I'll need auto differentiation.