# Expand Vector in Tensorflow and space elements with zeros

Tags: vector, tensorflow, expand

I would like to space vector elements from each others and fill it with zeros:

```
  a = [1, 5, 7, ..., 3]
```

Space elements of a with two zeros:

```
  b = [1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, ... , 3, 0, 0]
```

The number of zeros that I space the elements with should be flexible.

What's the best way to do this on the Graph in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do it as explained [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061808/how-does-tensorflow-indexing-work) (second example of the accepted answer)?

Basically I would first create `b` as a a vector of zeros, then compute the  indices which point into `b` for all values in `a` and then use the code from the linked post to assign the values of `a` to these indices.

Something like this maybe:

```
a = tf.constant(np.array([1, 3, 5, 7]))
dim = a.get_shape()[0].value
n = 2
b = tf.fill(dims=[dim*(n+1)], value=0.0)
new_indices = np.array([i + i*n for i in range(0, dim)])
# now call referenced code with new_indices to update `b`
```

I'm not sure that this is the best way per se, but it would get the job done.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me out! Now I got a new problem though: The function tf.sparse_to_dense is not implemented for GPU on r0.12. Same for tf.diag. Without the support my gradient calculation doesn't work, because I implemented it in GPU towers like in CIFAR10. I opened a new Question for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397950/tensorflow-gradient-calculation-with-sparse-tensors-on-gpu