# Tensorflow: Gradient Calculation with sparse tensors on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, sparse-matrix

I built up a tensorflow model similar to the GPU Implementation of CIFAR10. I have a basic model that is executed on every GPU while the variables for the network are on the CPU. Everything works fine as long as I don't use sparse tensors as weight matrices in the layers.

My sparse weight matrices are constructed with the function **tf.sparse_to_dense()** or **tf.diag()**. When I run it on the CPU everything works fine, but when I run it on the GPU I get the message that there is **no GPU implementation of these functions**.

Is there an alternative? How do I construct sparse weight matrices that are located on a CPU but trained on a GPU?

Comment: You can implement those operations in the GPU and let tensorflow use them.

Comment: Ok, I can always write stuff myself, but since I'm not a computer scientist this will take a lot of effort for me. I just think that this is such a standard problem that I have that I would have expected this issue is already solved in some way.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to open an Issue at Github for this?