# How do I use tensors for slicing in TensorFlow like NumPy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I have a two tensors, one that represents a list of vectors and another that represents a list of indices that correspond to each vector. I want to get the value of each vector that is at the corresponding index. This is how I would do this with numpy:

```
vectors = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
                    [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
                    [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
indices = np.array([1, 4, 3])
values = vectors[np.arange(3), indices]
# values: [1, 9, 13]
```

but when I try this where 'vectors' and 'indices' are TensorFlow tensors, it doesn't work. Is there a way to get the same result?

Comment: See if this helps out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736795/tensorflow-numpy-like-tensor-indexing