# Boolean indexing in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

It seems Tensorflow doesnot support boolean indexing. How can I do this in Tensorflow?

```
    import numpy as np

    A = np.array([3, 4, 5, -1, 6, -1, 7, 8])
    mask = (A == -1)

    print(A)

    A[mask] = [11, 12]

    print(A)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TensorFlow - numpy-like tensor indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736795/tensorflow-numpy-like-tensor-indexing)

Answer (score 1):

To extract elements with a boolean array, you can use [`boolean_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask):

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.InteractiveSession()

a = tf.constant([3, 4, 5, -1, 6, -1, 7, 8])
mask = tf.equal(a, -1)
tf.boolean_mask(a, mask).eval()
# array([-1, -1], dtype=int32)
```

Which however does not seem to support assignment. 
If the elements need to be updated to the same value, use `tf.where`, which can work for both constant and Variable:

```
a = tf.constant([3, 4, 5, -1, 6, -1, 7, 8])
mask = tf.equal(a, -1)
tf.where(mask, [11] * a.shape[0], a).eval()
# array([ 3,  4,  5, 11,  6, 11,  7,  8], dtype=int32)
```

If the updated values is an customized array with different values, we can use [`tf.scatter_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update), by converting the boolean mask to indices first, in which case `a` needs to be a **`Variable`**:

```
a = tf.Variable([3, 4, 5, -1, 6, -1, 7, 8])
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

mask = tf.equal(a, -1)
indices = tf.reshape(tf.where(mask), (-1,))
tf.scatter_update(a, indices, [11, 12]).eval()
# array([ 3,  4,  5, 11,  6, 12,  7,  8], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Do you also know if it is possible with the edit I made, so [11,12] instead of [11] (an arbitrary list with the same number as items as Trues in the mask)

Comment: Thanks, but what if a is not a Variable?